# Show that $(\int_\Omega |\nabla u|^2 + \int_\Omega |u|^2)^{1/2}$ is a norm in $H_0^1$

Tags: normed-spaces, sobolev-spaces

I am reviewing some material on Sobolev spaces and taking some time to derive the basics again. But I am unable to see how to show the triangle inequality for

$$
||u|| = \left( \int_\Omega|\nabla u|^2 dx + \int_\Omega|u|^2\right)^{1/2}.
$$

I tried using the triangle inequality for the $L^2$ norm, but to no end:

$$
||u+v|| = (||\nabla u + \nabla v||_2^2 + ||u + v||_2^2)^{1/2} \\ \leq \left( (||\nabla u||_2 + ||\nabla v||_2)^2 + (||u||_2 + ||v||_2)^2 \right)^{1/2} \\  \leq ||\nabla u||_2 +||\nabla v||_2 +||u||_2 + ||v||_2
$$

Any hint will be the most appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe show that the bilinear form $B(u, v) = \int_\Omega \langle \nabla u, \nabla v \rangle + \int_\Omega \langle u, v \rangle$ is an inner product?

Comment: Doesn't this follow from minkowski's inequality that $((a+b)^p+(c+d)^p)^{1/p} \leq (a^p+c^p)^{1/p} + (b^p+d^p)^{1/p}$ for $p\geq 1$ and $a,b,c,d\geq 0$? The $p=2$ reduces to Cauchy-Schwarz.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the comment by @user58955 suggested, use the Minkowski inequality (this process works for $W^{k,p}$):

\begin{align*}
\|u+v\|&=\left(\|\nabla u+\nabla v\|_2^2+\|u+v\|^2\right)^{1/2}\\
&\leq \left(\left(\|\nabla u\|_2+\|\nabla v\|_2\right)^2+\left(\|u\|_2+\|v\|_2\right)^2\right)^{1/2}\\
&\leq \left(\|\nabla u\|_2^2+\|u\|_2^2\right)^{1/2}+\left(\|\nabla v\|_2^2+\|v\|_2^2\right)^{1/2}\\
&=\|u\|+\|v\|.
\end{align*}
This is how it is done, for example, in Evans.